# Android: Change actionBar Title text to image

Tags: android, layout, styles, themes, android-actionbar

In the action bar there is Icon then Title

I want to put an image, instead of the titleText, so actionBar will be Icon then TitleImage right next to it, how can I do that ?

Can I make my own actionBar Layout ? or I can only edit it's style ?
I am talking about the HOLO LIGHT Theme.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look at http://actionbarsherlock.com/ for this level of customization.
It really easy to implement and you'll be able to do more than that.

Hope it helped